# Changing WKInterfaceLabel Text

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I currently have:

```
@IBOutlet var label: WKInterfaceLabel!
```

and

```
 let myString = "Swift Attributed String"
 let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue ]
 let myAttrString = NSAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: myAttribute)
 label.setAttributedText(myAttrString)
```

Currently this code does not change the text of the label. Is there something obvious I am missing? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly fine but for only textcolor 
You do not need to use attributed property you can directly use **setTextColor()** property.

```
label.setTextColor(UIColor.blue)
label.setText(myString)
```

You can refer [WKInterfaceLabel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacelabel#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceLabel) and [setTextColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacelabel/1620832-settextcolor)